# How can i add a command to the meteor mupx start script?

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment, docker, graphicsmagick

I want to add:

> RUN apt-get install graphicsmagick -y

to my meteor mupx application start script. When i add it to /opt/myapp/config/start.sh its obviously overritten by my next deployment. Where is the "template" file to build the "/opt/myapp/config/start.sh" script located?

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

It's located at: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/templates/linux`

Comment: Can you please share your start script? I am have the same issue.

Comment: @Nate Berbettini, sorry didn´t read it before, i posted it as second answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@ Jason Cochran, yes 4 sure

```
   APPNAME=<%= appName %>
   APP_PATH=/opt/$APPNAME
   BUNDLE_PATH=$APP_PATH/current
   ENV_FILE=$APP_PATH/config/env.list
   PORT=<%= port %>
   USE_LOCAL_MONGO=<%= useLocalMongo? "1" : "0" %>

   # remove previous version of the app, if exists
   docker rm -f $APPNAME

   # remove frontend container if exists
   docker rm -f $APPNAME-frontend
   # Thats the importent part for graphicsmagick
   set -e
   docker build -t meteorhacks/meteord:app - << EOF
   FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
   RUN apt-get install graphicsmagick -y
   EOF

   if [ "$USE_LOCAL_MONGO" == "1" ]; then
     docker run \
 -d \
 --restart=always \
 --publish=$PORT:80 \
 --volume=$BUNDLE_PATH:/bundle \
 --env-file=$ENV_FILE \
 --link=mongodb:mongodb \
 --hostname="$HOSTNAME-$APPNAME" \
 --env=MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/$APPNAME \
 --name=$APPNAME \
 meteorhacks/meteord:app
   else
 docker run \
 -d \
 --restart=always \
 --publish=$PORT:80 \
 --volume=$BUNDLE_PATH:/bundle \
 --hostname="$HOSTNAME-$APPNAME" \
 --env-file=$ENV_FILE \
 --name=$APPNAME \
 meteorhacks/meteord:app
   fi

<% if(typeof sslConfig === "object")  { %>
docker pull meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server:latest
docker run \
-d \
--restart=always \
--volume=/opt/$APPNAME/config/bundle.crt:/bundle.crt \
--volume=/opt/$APPNAME/config/private.key:/private.key \
--link=$APPNAME:backend \
--publish=<%= sslConfig.port %>:443 \
--name=$APPNAME-frontend \
meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server /start.sh
<% } %>
```